# Copy-paste of selections with Xlib in X11: XA_TARGETS array of atoms

Tags: selection, paste, xlib, gdk

I've implemented copy-paste of text strings in an Xlib program.
When my program owns the current selection, and I paste into xterm,
or into a text field in gimp, or into firefox, it works fine: the program I'm
pasting into sends a SelectionRequest event to my program with
target XA_UTF8_STRING ("UTF8_STRING"), and my program responds appropriately
and the string is pasted.

However, when my program owns the current selection, and I try to paste into
a message composition window in Thunderbird (version 16.0.2)
or text field in the SeaMonkey web browser (version 2.20), Thunderbird and SeaMonkey
send a SelectionRequest event to my program with target XA_TARGETS ("TARGETS"),
and something goes wrong.  My understanding is that my program is supposed to respond
with an array of the targets that it can provide - the relevant code of my program
is below.  (Note that this is on a 64 bit machine, and the Atom type is 64 bits).
Thunderbird / SeaMonkey don't seem happy with my response, because they then
send my program many subsequent SelectionRequest events, with different targets,
as if they are trying to see which one I will return (they try
application/x-moz-nativehtml, text/html, application/x-moz-file, image/png,
image/jpeg, image/gif) and then finally try the target UTF8_STRING, to which my 
code responds successfully and the string is pasted.  This can all take 1 second
or more, so there is a noticeable delay before the string is pasted.

To try to debug things, I modified my code so that when I paste into *my* program,
and another program is the owner, I send them a SelectionRequest event with
target XA_TARGETS, so I could see how Thunderbird or SeaMonkey respond.
I get back a SelectionNotify event, with target XA_TARGETS, and the event's property set
to the one I requested, and when I read that property on my own window, I find
it is an array of type XA_ATOM, format 32, and length 0.  So I don't seem to get
any array of targets from Thunderbird or SeaMonkey when I ask them for it.

Platform: Ubuntu 12.10 Linux x86_64

A reference I used:
http://svn.gna.org/svn/warzone/trunk/lib/betawidget/src/platform/sdl/clipboardX11.c

```
...
if ( event.type == SelectionRequest ) {
  Atom propertyOfRequestorToSet = event.xselectionrequest.property==None ? XA_PRIMARY : event.xselectionrequest.property;

  XSelectionEvent selEvent;
  selEvent.type = SelectionNotify;
  // selEvent.serial = event.xselectionrequest.serial; // I don't know if this is correct
  selEvent.send_event = True;
  selEvent.display = my_display;
  selEvent.requestor = event.xselectionrequest.requestor;
  selEvent.selection = event.xselectionrequest.selection;
  selEvent.target = event.xselectionrequest.target;
  selEvent.property = None;
  selEvent.time = event.xselectionrequest.time;

  if ( event.xselectionrequest.target == XA_TARGETS ) {

    Atom possibleTargets[] = { XA_UTF8_STRING, XA_STRING, XA_TEXT }; // [Note 2]

    // I checked, and this call returns 1
    XChangeProperty( my_display, event.xselectionrequest.requestor,
      propertyOfRequestorToSet,
      XA_ATOM,
      32, // 32 bits actually means long, according to what I've read // [Note 1]
      PropModeReplace,
      (unsigned char *) possibleTargets,
      sizeof(possibleTargets)/sizeof(possibleTargets[0])  // [Note 3]
    );

    selEvent.property = propertyOfRequestorToSet;
  }
  else ... {
  }

  if ( 0 == XSendEvent( my_display, selEvent.requestor, False, 0L, (XEvent*)&selEvent ) ) {
    printf("call to XSendEvent() failed\n");
  }
}
```

Note 1: if I pass 64, I get a BadValue X Error.

Note 2: I've tried replacing this line with
int possibleTargets[] = { (int)XA_STRING, (int)XA_UTF8_STRING, (int)XA_TEXT };
so that the array would be of 32-bit words, and the behavior is the same.

Note 3: I've tried passing an array of 1 or even 0 elements, and the behavior is the same.

In the call to XChangeProperty(), I also tried passing a format of 8 and length of sizeof(possibleTargets),
as in the answer at
( [Clipboard selection transfer does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570315/c-x11-clipboard-selection-transfer-does-not-work/10570849) )
but I still observe the same behavior.

Comment: Try `Atom possibleTargets[] = {XA_TARGETS, XA_MULTIPLE, XA_UTF8_STRING, XA_STRING, XA_TEXT};`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the behavior seems the same with that change.

Comment: What happens if you simplify it, e.g., `Atom possibleTargets[] = {XA_TARGETS, XA_STRING};` ?

Comment: Also, from "Known bugs" listed on http://www.edwardrosten.com/code/x11.html, "Some programs want the type of TARGETS to be TARGETS (not ATOM)."

Comment: Look [here](http://www.edwardrosten.com/code/dist/x_clipboard-1.0/selection.cc), this standalone program works, prints debugging output and takes less than a second to paste. (Firefox indeed behaves more or less like you describe, other programs are more sane).

Comment: In 64-bit programs 32-bit properties are passed as array of 64-bit values while the upper 32 bits of each value are discarded. The type `Atom` is defined as 64 bit type there. The function argument however is `32` and not `64`.